# finding second order differential and Hessian

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $$g : \Bbb R^n → \Bbb R\\
x \mapsto g(x) := \sum_{i=1}^m  (r_i (x))^2$$ where the $r_i : \Bbb R^n → \Bbb R$ are twice differentiable.

Compute the differential $dg x$ , then the gradient $∇g(x)$.
Compute the second order differential $d^2 g x$ , then the hessian $∇^2g(x)$.

This is what I have done to derive the gradient and think is correct .

Lets take the sum after calculations …
$r(x+h) = r(x) + dfx(h)+ o(h)$   : since $r$ is twice differentiable

$$g(x+h)=(r(x+h))^2   = (r(x))2 +(dfx(h))^2 + 2r(x)dfx(h) + ..$$
and considering only the linear function of h

$$\langle Vg(x),h\rangle =2r(x)\langle ∇r(x), h\rangle\\
\implies ∇g(x) =2r(x)∇r(x)$$
so far so good …

for calculating $∇^2g(x)$ , I would need the right formula as am not sure how to break down the compound function in determining the derivative. Appreciate any help ..sorry if this looks trivial to many .

Comment: I have edited your math. Can you please look over it to see that everything looks good. If there is anything I've done wrong, you can click the "edit" button to see what I have done or otherwise check out [this guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

The Hessian of a twice differentiable function $g:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is the matrix
$$\left(H_{j,k}(x)\right)_{j,k=1,\ldots,n} :=\left(\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x_j\partial x_k}(x)\right)_{j,k=1,\ldots,n}.$$
You already determined the gradient
$$\nabla g(x)=\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_j}(x)\right)_{j=1,\ldots,n}$$
so all that's left to do is derive the components of the gradient by $x_k$.